# How to make tags visible

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to make certain tags that certain players get but I want them to be visible above the players head, and as far as I know that doesn't naturally happen, is there some sort of command or option to make custom tags visible above name tags or anything like that?

Comment: Like scoreboard objectives?

Answer (score 1):

### Bedrock Edition

No, unfortunately there is no direct or easy way to do this with tags that you apply through `/tag`. The only thing you can do is set a scoreboard objective to be above a players head.

However, it might still be possible, thanks to add-ons.

You could add the various tags as various [custom particles](https://bedrock.dev/docs/stable/Particles). Next, change the player model, animations and animation controllers to include these particles, probably based on whether they have the tag or not.
I am not sure if you can detect tags in animation controllers directly, if not you'll need to work around this by adding `environment_sensors` to the player entity that checks for the various tags being present (or not) and adding a corresponding component group  with an attribute that is detectable in animation controllers, but that otherwise doesn't affect game-play.

Here is the official documentation / guide on particles, which also includes explanations on how to add them to entities:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/documents/particleeffects

### Java Edition

A possible workaround would be to use Area Effect Clouds / Armor Stands or even better the upcoming 1.19.4 [Display entity](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Display) to display the tags in an entity name, while constantly teleporting the entity above the player. This will visually lag behind a bit, but it is a possible solution.

Alternatively you could think about two things (if you only need one tag to be displayed at a time):

1. you can set one scoreboard objective to be displayed above the players heads.
2. Teams let you set pre- and suffixes, which appear around the players name above their heads. So you could set the prefix to `[tag]`  and players in this team would look like `[tag] Playername` in-game.